# How can I change how eclipse invokes gdb in linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, opengl

In short, I need to understand how to configure eclipse to run "optirun gbd" instead of "gdb". An explanation of what exactly I'm trying to accomplish follows.

I need to run my debug app in eclipse such that it will use the nvidia optimus card instead of the integrated card. My app requires opengl support that is only available this way.

I've got a laptop with an nvidia optimus video card. I'm running linux (ubuntu). I've successfully set up bumblebee such that I can take advantage of the optimus technology. This requires that, to use the nvidia card, I run a given program "foo" with the program "optirun:" `optirun foo`.

I need to configure eclipse to launch my program in debug mode under optirun. If I run from command line: `optirun gdb app` everything works as expected.

Edit: Changing the "GDB Debugger" field inside the debug configuration to `optirun gdb` does not work. Lanching eclipse by `optirun eclipse` does, however. But this is a detriment to battery life.

Comment: If you do not need to debug it immediately, run it with `optirun` and then use `gdb --pid ...` to attach the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Debug Configurations", open "Debugger" tab. Change "GDB debugger" from `gdb` to `optirun gdb`.

Works in Eclipse Juno, Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm sure eclipse uses the shell to execute the program, a workaround is to alias `gdb` to `optirun gdb` in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It did work from command line, though, as expected.

Comment: Curiosity now, try putting the alias in `/etc/environment`. While that's hardly an ideal situation, its the only other "environment" file that's called all the time

Answer (score 0):

I look into this issue today and I found another solution. As long as you have Bumblebee installed (http://www.bumblebee-project.org/) and you know you can attach optirun to an executable (try with glxgears for example) you can attach it to cuda-gdb.

What I did is create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
optirun /usr/local/cuda/bin/cuda-gdb $*
```

And save it to /usr/local/cuda/bin or somewhere else it doesn't matter, with the appropriate permissions for execution (755).
What it does is very simple, it runs optirun cuda-gdb args where args is whatever the command line sends it.
In terminal just run opti_cuda-gdb with or without arguments.

For example I named it opti_cuda-gdb and placed it in that directory (which conveniently is added to the path if CUDA is properly configured).
If you use an IDE to develop, like say Netbeans, point the debbuger executable to that script.
I've been successfully compiled and debbuged code using CuSparse and CuBlas with NetBeans running in a SAMSUNG SF410 with Nvidia Optimus and Ubuntu 11.04 and 11.10.

I'm open to provide further details if you think I omitted something.